# How to slice letters from string with angular pipe?

Tags: angular, error-handling, pipe

When I get Promise error, it consists of a lot of letters so I want to shorten it with a pipe, but error doesn't show. Why?

**Service:**

```
 error: any;

async register(email: string, password: string) {
  try {
   await this.afs.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  } catch (err:any) {
    this.error = err;
  }
}
```

**TS:**

```
err:any;

register() {

this.auth.register('email', 'password');

this.err = this.auth.error;

}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <mat-error>{{err}}</mat-error>
```

**This code is working but with pipe transform it not working:**

```
@Pipe({name: 'error'});

export class FormErrorPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string): any {
    if (value) {
     return value.slice(10)
    }  
    return null;
  }
}

<mat-error>{{err | error}}</mat-error>
```

**Any solution? Thanks!**

Comment: what is coming inside err? I guess its a error object not a string. Am i correct?

Comment: yes, it is not a string :)

Comment: read message property to slice and it will work.

Comment: I've used toString() method and its works. thanks!

Comment: should i post it as answer for you to approve?